# How to load a local xlsx file in a UIWebView using Xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, uiwebview, xamarin.ios

Hello I am trying to load a xlsx file in a UIWebView Prior to the documentation Xamarin provides you should be able to load this file with this code:

```
using Foundation;
using System;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.IO;
using UIKit;

namespace Justice_Compliance_Monitoring_App
{
    partial class SurveyView : UIViewController
    {
        UIWebView webView;

        public SurveyView (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();
            View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;

            webView = new UIWebView(View.Bounds);
            View.AddSubview(webView);

            //string fileName = "Loading a Web Page.pdf";
            //string fileName = "Loading a Web Page.docx";
            string fileName = "servey.xlsx";

            string localDocUrl = Path.Combine(NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath, fileName);
            webView.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(localDocUrl, false)));

            // if this is false, page will be 'zoomed in' to normal size
            webView.ScalesPageToFit = true;
        }

        public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
        {
            base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();
            // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
        }
    }
}
```

However when I test this in the emulator I get a blank white screen   and the file never loads

what am I doing wrong?

Any suggestions would be amazing

Thanks in advance!

Comment: does the file exist in the root of your project with a Build Action set to Content?

Comment: Jason that worked but the file is read only so i'll have to look into another way to open and edit in iOS thanks for your help!

Comment: All content inside of the app bundle is read-only.  You can copy the file to a writable folder and edit it from there.

Comment: ok i'll try that so I just make a new folder in the project and put the xlsx file in there and change the code to look in that folder?

Comment: no, anything inside the app bundle is read-only.  You will have to create a new folder at runtime that is not in the bundle, and copy your file there.  Then you will have a writable copy of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to Jason's suggestion changing the Build Action to Content worked but the file is read only so i'll have to look into another way to open and edit in iOS
Once again Thank you Jason for your help!